# Two jQuery UI datepickers with different options

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Example is here http://jsfiddle.net/68z9dkyb/5/

Have 2 datepickers.

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date_first_registration">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="inspection_valid_until">
```

For one want date range start 100 years before and end this year. For another to start one year before and end 20 years after the current year.

Tried this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dayNamesMin: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Frid ", "Sat"],
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    }).val()
    $("#date_first_registration").datepicker({
        yearRange: "-100:+0"
    }).val()
    $("#inspection_valid_until").datepicker({
        yearRange: "-1:+20"
    }).val()
});
```

But does not work. From my understanding i set all for `.datepicker`, then set different date ranges for each id. But does not work. What need to correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.datepicker` class general code and implement separate code for each datepicker like

```
$("#date_first_registration").datepicker({ 
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dayNamesMin: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Frid ", "Sat"],  
yearRange: "-100:+0"
}).val()


$("#inspection_valid_until").datepicker({ 
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dayNamesMin: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Frid ", "Sat"],  
    yearRange: "-1:+20"
}).val()
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/68z9dkyb/6/)

Comment: My idea was not to repeat code, like `changeMonth: true`. In your answer there is short code. But if  longer code. Is it possible not repeat the same code for each id? To set default code for class and then ad different code for each id?

Answer (score 2):

**1:** You can use the [`option`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option) parameter:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dayNamesMin: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Frid ", "Sat"],
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
  $("#date_first_registration").datepicker("option", "yearRange", "-100:+0");
  $("#inspection_valid_until").datepicker("option", "yearRange", "-1:+20");
});
```

```css
@import url("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css");
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input class="datepicker" id="date_first_registration">
<input class="datepicker" id="inspection_valid_until">
```

**2:** An alternate would be to use object and [`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/):

```js
$(function() {
  var defaults = {
    showOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dayNamesMin: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Frid ", "Sat"],
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  };
  $("#date_first_registration").datepicker($.extend({}, defaults, {
    yearRange: "-100:+0"
  }));
  $("#inspection_valid_until").datepicker($.extend({}, defaults, {
    yearRange: "-1:+20"
  }));
});
```

```css
@import url("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css");
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input class="datepicker" id="date_first_registration">
<input class="datepicker" id="inspection_valid_until">
```